# How can I make a coin using Monero?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mining-pools, security, cryptonote, altcoin

I am developing a coin using the Monero git code, so I want to know what is the setup we need to follow to create our own coin using Monero.

1. Coin development
2. Coin Api development
3. Coin explore
4. Coin Web wallet
5. Coin pool

Let me know of any document or video. I successfully developped a coin using Cryptonote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred setup to fork a new coin from Monero is:

- a Linux system, with enough memory (4 GB should be enough, more for parallel building), and a fast SSD (well, for Monero it's a must, but a fork will be fine with a HDD since you won't get the traffic when you start out).
- a set of programming tools, including a C compiler, make, cmake, etc.
- The dependencies mentioned in the README.md file, which you've no doubt perused already.
- the source from https://github.com/monero-project/monero

There are two pool codebases which you'll want to adapt:
The original one is at https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool and used by most pools still. It uses redis, as you'll find in its well made README.md file.
A new pool codebase is at https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool.

For an explorer, you can start from https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer

For a web wallet, https://mymonero.com has all its Javascript open source. You'll need a backend, for which you can start off https://github.com/moneroexamples/openmonero

With all these tools, you'll be ready to start development in no time!

You then have two basic paths ahead:

- the hard way: you can pour a lot of time and work in your fork to make something useful and attract people to your innovative changes
- the easy way: you can pour a lot of time into making it seem you have something shiny while neglecting any substantive work on the fork, and attract suckers who don't know any better - worked short term for many people before

Good luck, and may you choose wisely.

Comment: How can i add pre-mine coin in monero code?

Comment: how to add --print-genesis-tx  in monero or how to add  genesis-tx ?