# Monero Forking Guide

Tags: monerod, monero-forks, github, user-guide

I have been recommended to use the CryptoNote Forking guide (https://cryptonotestarter.org/inner.html)  as a basis for Forking Monero. However, there are a number of differences. For example, the following instructions refer to variables and locations that do not exist in the Monero source code but they do in CryptoNote:

//Name Your Coin Section

> — in src/CMakeList.txt file — set_property(TARGET daemon PROPERTY
>   OUTPUT_NAME "YOURCOINNAMEd") Example:  set_property(TARGET daemon
>   PROPERTY OUTPUT_NAME "furiouscoind")

//NETWORKING - Section 3

> Seed nodes — src/CryptoNoteConfig.h Add IP addresses of your seed
>   nodes.  Example:  const std::initializer_list SEED_NODES
>   = {   "111.11.11.11:17236",   "222.22.22.22:17236", };

Would anyone be able to advise as to

1. Does anyone have a more up-to-date Monero Forking guide?
2. Where do I put the IP Addresses of the SEED nodes
3. Where do set the Output Name? Does the const char CRYPTONOTE_NAME[] = "COINNAME" now suffice?
4. Is there anything else not included in the CryptoNote Forking Guide that I need to be aware of when trying to Fork Monero?

Comment: The get_seed_nodes(cryptonote::network_type nettype) function in the net_node.inl file contains IP Addresses of SEED nodes. However, where then do I set the nettype variable?

Comment: The Monero codebase has diverged from Cryptonote, so that forking guide will in some cases give you a conceptual overview of what you need to change, and in other cases the source code will be identical in both places. I suggest what you should do is to find a recent clone of Monero that someone else has made the source code available for, and then do a 'diff' between the codebases to see all of the things that they changed.

Comment: did you get this working? seems to me that cryptonote is pretty much dead with just a few new coins coming out and the current cryptonight coins are all dying in the exchanges.
monero is unforkable in my opinion, hence no fork guide, and no one willing to help you work on your altcoin.

Comment: Ask for it to the disappeared cryptonote team people... You may find it on reddit... :D

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5968)

Comment: Not updated and exhaustive but you can find some useful info at https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/how-can-i-make-a-coin-using-monero

Answer (score 0):

Try the forknote generator, you can find it at this address: https://github.com/forknote/monero-generator.